# Finding a common value in dataframe and returning the keys corresponding to the sam

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, loops

importing the required files to perform the task

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

creating function to convert the data to string

```
def stringconvert(data):

    str1=""
    for d in data:
        str1=str1+d+' '
    return str1
```

below are the sample dataframe to compare

```
p=pd.DataFrames({'Keys':['A2000002676-111','A2000002682-111','A2000002683-111','A2000002690-111']})
p1=pd.DataFrames({'POLI':['A2000002676-111','A2000002682-111','A2000002683-111','A2000002690-111'],'PRCTR':['30054','501499','501499','30054']})
```

Codes to compare the availability of Keys in another data frame and returning the value

```
keyval=[]
keydata=[]
matchlist=[]
matchdatalist=[]

for x,y in p.iterrows():
    data=y['Keys']
for x1,y1 in P1.iterrows():
    key=y1['POLI']
    if key==data:
        keyval.append(key)
        keydata.append(y1['PRCTR'])
matchkey=''
matchkeydata=''
matchkey = stringconvert(keyval)
if matchkey =="":
    matchkey='No Match'
    matchkeydata='Empty Data'
else:
    matchkeydata = stringconvert(keydata)
    
matchlist.append(matchkey)
matchdatalist.append(matchkeydata)
keyval=[]
keydata=[]

p['pcr']=pd.DataFrame(data=matchdatalist)
print(p)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, but is this just a simple merge -- `p.merge(p1, how='left', left_on='Keys', right_on='POLI')` ?

Comment: merge will give the data in different rows, but i need all the common data in single cell against the keys. i am getting the output for small data. but when the dataset is huge, it consume long time and no output. is there any better way to do it